# working 2.3.3 NFC demo

Tags: nfc

has anybody found a working NFCdemo app for reading and writing data from real tags?

Best Regards,
H.

Answer (score 0):

I have a working demo on my home computer. If enough people need it (and there isn't much available on the internet), I'll share it tonight.

Comment: That would be lovely to get it all going. (for a rookie like me) its quite hard to start from 0.

Comment: it seems that the tags I have are Mifare classic 1k. My Nexus s can communicate with it if I use NXP tagwriter, but still so far (so bad)  - no success with the NFCdemo modifications

Comment: @azharb it would be great if you could share the code for the demo app you have!!